# Why do I get a random MAC address every boot in a linux embedded system?

Tags: linux, networking, raspberry-pi, embedded, mac-address

I started messing around with my raspberry pi and I build a simple linux embedded system using buildroot and I found my IP address was different to what I was expecting (I had DHCP configured) then I found that my MAC address was different everytime I booted the system, when I was using Raspbian the MAC was always the same. I know how to spoof the MAC but I would like to know why does this happens. Can someone help me?

Comment: The MAC address is stored some place on your Pi (eeprom?).  The original distribution knew this location, and read it and set the interface accordingly.

Comment: Sorry to ask again after 6 days, I don't know even if you'll answer, but then, is there a way to configure buildroot to make it know where to look to get it?

Comment: Unfortunately I do not know the answer to that.  It is likely in some driver code somewhere, but while I have been doing embedded Linux for 15 years, I do not know the Pi.  It would likely be a make a great question at http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Sorry for answering so late, but I've just found out it was because I was using an old version of the bootloader I was using (uBoot)